# Does a final .apk include images not referenced/used?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Do I need to go through the complete repository and delete `Drawables` not referenced in the code, or does the apk automatically not include `Drawables` never used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other APK-reducing tips at: http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, no. Your apk will include everything you put in it.

**To remove unused code** use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

**To remove unused resources**, you can include this in your build.gradle.

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LoyalRayne I was hoping there would be an easy solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this followings to remove unused images. 
http://keepsafe-engineering.tumblr.com/post/85828806276/remove-unused-android-resources
https://github.com/instructure/android-ImageSweep and http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/

Hope it may help you.